# WordPress: How do I edit the "loading" and "decoding" media attributes of a specific image?

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, wordpress-media

In WordPress, media items (images) have attributes associated with them that control how they get rendered as HTML. WP version 5.5 added the `loading` attribute and version 6.1 added the `decoding` attribute.

How do I actually change the values of these attributes for a specific image?

Comment: How are you outputting this image? Or do you want this to occur globally for one specific image? `wp_img_tag_add_decoding_attr` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_img_tag_add_decoding_attr/ or you can probably use this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes/

Comment: I'm looking to change the attributes of one specific image, not globally. And I appreciate the pointers to the API docs, but I was hoping there was something in the Admin UI that allowed non-technical users to update the media attributes. It seems odd that WP would implement this functionality but not expose it in the UI anywhere.

Comment: You could technically use ACF or custom meta field to add fields to the UI for non-tech users, but then use the docs referenced to query that data for image output.